# Равномерный шаг UISlider

Tags: ios

Я сделал UISlider но при движении самого слайдера значение меняется произвольно (12.38, 13.43, 1,54), мне нужно сделать округление к 0 или 5, то есть чтоб последняя цифра была 0 или 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Типа такого:

```
- (void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)slider {
    int roundedValue = round(slider.value/5.0)*5;
}
```

Если после округления вы хотите, чтобы слайдер стоял на позиции соответствующей округленному значению:

```
self.slider.value = roundedValue;
```

Comment: Спасибо, я уже решил это задание подобным методом, только я использовал значение умножения и деления на 20

Answer (score 2):

В методе, отвечающем за изменение значения слайдера, делайте

```
 - (void)changeValue:(UISlider *)sender{
     float decimalPart  = sender.value - floor(sender.value);
     int integerPart =(int)floorf(sender.value);
     if (decimal < 0.25){
        self.slider.value = integerPart;
     }else if (decimal >= 0.25 && decimal < 0.75){
        self.slider.value = integerPart + 0.5;
     }else { 
        self.slider.value = integerPart + 1;
     }
}
```